# Python request prevent read too big website

Tags: python, python-requests

Is there any option to prevent read too big website output? For example if the website makes infinitive output etc, even detect such website maybe.

Comment: Can you explain in more detail?
I cant understand your question.

Comment: you read the website using Request library but the website makes too big output like 20 MB and you want to prevent this and even detect it. Request reads the website until memory crash.

Answer (score 1):

if the website support HEAD ,you can send a head req,like this:

```
rsp=requests.head(url)
len_content=rsp.headers["Content-Length"]
if len_content > 1*1024:
    do_something.
```

if the website not support HEAD, use "stream" GET instead.

```
with requests.Session() as s:  
    rsp = s.get(url, stream=True)
```

I happened to have a similar problem the other day.